# OnRowDataBound error in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to show email, decrypted password and encrypted password in my gridview

```
  <asp:GridView ID="gvUsers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
 <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="email" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Password" HeaderText=" encrypted password" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Password" HeaderText="decrypted password" />

    </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

---

this is code behind where I am binding gridview

```
   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Memberships"))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    gvUsers.DataSource = dt;
                    gvUsers.DataBind();
                }
            }

  protected void gvUsers_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
       if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      {
           e.Row.Cells[2].Text = Decrypt(e.Row.Cells[2].Text);
       }
    }

    private string Decrypt(string cipherText)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
        byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return cipherText;

    }
```

The problem is when I am calling OnRowDataBound, page is not running and error comes "Could not copy the file pageName.dll" because it was not found. Why is this so? IF I exclude OnRowDataBound event from gridview page runs without any error. But for password decryption I have to call OnRowDataBound. Help?

Answer (score 0):

You have given wrong name of your event

Replace below

```
  <asp:GridView ID="gvUsers" runat="server" 
       AutoGenerateColumns="false"  OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
```

With

```
  <asp:GridView ID="gvUsers" runat="server" 
       AutoGenerateColumns="false"  OnRowDataBound="gvUsers_RowDataBound">
```

Hope this will sort your issue.

Comment: ok can you provide the exact error message generated by debugger?

Comment: ----Could not copy the file "obj\Debug\MatrimonialSite.dll" because it was not found----

MatrimonialSite is my project name

Comment: Its something VS related issue, try to restart your project than clean and rebuild it again

Comment: Its coming on rebuilding also